# Vue3 - D3 adding a path to a cell - not visualized

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vuejs3

I found a GitHub version of Mike Bostock's adjacency matrix visualization, using data from Les Miserables.

I transformed it into Vue3 code, and with the help of this community, got a functional prototype.

In my offline d3 code, I implemented some d3 code that added a path to each cell, which worked fine:

```
cell
.append("path")
.filter(function(d) { return ((d.z % 231== 0) | d.z ==231) })
.attr("d", "M 8.4 70 L 0 70 L 0 0 L 9.8 0 L 35 48.8 L 60 0 L 69.9 0 L 69.9 70 L 61.5 70 L 61.5 15 L 38.1 60 L 31.8 60 L 8.4 15.1 L 8.4 70 Z")
.attr("fill", "#030104")
.attr("opacity", function(d) {  return  z(d.z); })
.attr("class", "icon")
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("height", x.rangeBand())
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                var scale = (x.rangeBand()/((this.getBBox()['height']+this.getBBox()['width'])/2)*0.9);
        var marginTop = (x.rangeBand()-(this.getBBox()['height']*scale))/2;
        var marginLeft = (x.rangeBand()-(this.getBBox()['width']*scale))/2;
            return "translate(" + (x(d.x)+marginLeft) + ", " + marginTop + ")scale("+ scale +")";
    })
```

However, I can't get it to work in Vue. I already fixed the rangeBand to bandwidth and some other small things. But nothing is getting visualized. Perhaps this functionality is not supported anymore by this newer d3 version?

Here is an online version of the transformed visualization in Vue3 format:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-gould-dejiuj?file=/src/components/Miserables.vue
(click on the Miserable link, the concerned code is located on line 1912).

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `path` elements are appended to the `rect` elements, but `rect` cannot have children. Also, the transition values are `NaN`.

Instead, I would put the `rect` and the `path` in a `g` element. You can then translate the `g` instead of `rect` and `path` individually:

```
    function fillrow(row) {

      const groups = d3
        .select(this)
        .selectAll(".cell")
        .data(row.filter((d) => d.z))
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr("class", "cell") // <---- cell is now the group element
        .attr("transform", (d, i)  => `translate(${that.x(d.x)}, 0)`); // <---- translate whole group
        
      groups
        .append("rect")
        .attr(...) // <---- no need to set x
        
      groups
        .append("path")
        .attr(...) // <---- no need to set translate
        
    }
```

and in your `order()` function:

```
    order(value) {
      this.x.domain(this.orders[value]);

      const t = this.svg.transition().duration(2500);

      t.selectAll(".row")
        .delay((d, i) => this.x(i) * 4)
        .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(0, ${this.x(i)})`)
        .selectAll('.cell')
        .attr("transform", (d)  => `translate(${this.x(d.x)}, 0)`); // <---- translate group instead of rect
      ...
    },
```

This also fixes the issue with the `NaN` in the path transform.

Here is the [updated playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-miserables-p79kw7?file=/src/components/Miserables.vue)

Comment: Thanks a million, Moritz, works as a charm. Also thanks for the explanation, quite helpful.